# How does a Circular Light Source create Shadows with Darker Edges Sometimes?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, diffraction, shadow

**Problem:**
There is a room where the light fixture is circular*. Shadows of objects in this room are darkest in the center and brighter toward the edges, except for my phone charger. Its shadow is darkest at the edges and brightest in the center. In addition, the bottom of all shadows are darker than the top. To illustrate, I took a picture of the light source, the bedframe with shadow, and my phone charger with shadow:

[image: Light Source]
[image: Bedframe and shadow]
[image: Phone charger and shadow]

**Hypothesis:**
I do have a hypothesis for why the phone charges has darker shadows near the edges. First, I assumed I could model the circular light source as a series of point light sources, each of which causes its own shadow on the wall. Places where more of these individual shadows overlap are darker than places where less overlap. For a thick object, the most individual shadows overlap in the center of the overall shadow. In this diagram, the yellow circles are point light sources, the black lines trace the lights rays, the brown rectangle is an object blocking the light, and the blue rectangle is the wall where the shadow is cast. 1S, 2S, and 3S indicate how many shadows overlap in that region of the wall:

[image: Shadows cast from 3 evenly spaced points onto a large object]

For extremely thin objects, the shadows are also thinner, causing them to overlap less:

[image: Shadows cast from 3 evenly spaced points onto a small object]

However, when you project a circle into 1D, more points end up near the edges than the center. If you allow for more points near the edges, you do get some overlap:

[image: Shadows cast from 5 unevenly spaced points on a small object]

This same effect does happen for thick objects, but since the shadows are larger, they overlap in the center and the edge:

[image: Shadows cast from 3 unevenly spaced points onto a thick object]

In summary, if the point light sources are evenly spaced, then all objects would cast shadows with darker centers and brighter edges; if the point light sources are unevenly spaced, then large objects will still cast shadows with darker centers, but thin object would cast shadows with darker edges.

**Hypothesis Problems:**
There are 2 problems with this hypothesis. First, exactly what determines if an objects casts shadows like a thick object or thin object? I am not really sure how to go about solving the problem. My guess is that the size of the object compared to the distance between the object and the wall is more important than the absolute size of the object. This is because when I first made my diagrams my thick object had darker edges, a problem I solved by moving the wall closer to the object:

[image: Shadows cast from 3 evenly spaced points onto a thick object with wall further away]

This diagram has the points evenly spaced and still produces the darker edges effect!

Second, why is the bottom of shadows darker than the top? This effect is more visible on the phone charger, but it does happen with the bedframe too. My guess is that is has something to do with the angle of the light source, which is parallel to the ceiling and therefor perpendicular to the wall. I took pictures with the phone charger near the floor and ceiling, and the darker bottom effect was definitely stronger in the former:

[image: Phone charger with shadow near the floor]
[image: Phone charger with shadow near the ceiling]

If anyone has any ideas on what are causing these two effects, I would be very grateful.

*Technically, it is a bunch of LEDs embedded in a clear plastic ring such that the light they give off shines out the bottom of the ring. I am pretty sure this acts like a true circular light source because you can only make out the individual LEDs if you turn the brightness way down.

Comment: You are on the right track. Google penumbra. Here is an example site http://www.differencebetween.net/science/difference-between-penumbra-and-umbra/